# ZXing Library running perfectly fine in iOS 4.3, generates errors in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, qr-code, zxing, ios5

I have integrated the Zxing Library for QRCode Reader in one of my iPhone app.

It was running fine when I was using iOS 4.3 SDK.

But after I have installed iOS 5 SDK and Mac OS Lion on my Mac, it has started giving errors like

[image]

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Are you running the latest code out of svn? There hasn't been a release since iOS went public so there may be changes you're missing.

Are you compiling with Xcode 4.2? There are problems with earlier Xcode versions and they aren't tested with current code.

If you still have the problem, you'd need to show more detail. Selecting the error, then right-click >> "reveal in log" should show the raw compiler error (though it depends on the compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going mad with that problem, but I found the solution!

Redownload the 1.7 version, replace all files, build, close xcode and rebuild the project! It should work :)